# How can i right click and open in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datatables

**i want to open my link data in right click and open that  for now i am doing
window.location = "/MMPDataQuality/ViewMMPReferenceData?validator_id=" + id;**  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEmaB.png

Comment: Use `<a>` instead of `<button>`. Then this feature is automatically available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below snippet.

```
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
```

Sample html page

```
<html>
<body>
<a onClick="javascript:openInTab('https://facebook.com')" href="" target>facebook</a>
<script>
function openInTab(url){
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this only help in open in right click. i want to use popup right click which is underlined in picture asked in question  – @Eanthmue

Comment: Check my sample html page.